# Why is packet-sniffing possible?

Tags: packet-sniffers, man-in-the-middle, network-analysis

I can't wrap my head around how packet-sniffers can be used by anyone on the network.

I know very little about how networks work, but let me put it this way: suppose the mailman comes around delivering a package to my doorstep. Why is is that I'm able to rifle though all his other packages and look around? Shouldn't the mailman only hand me packages that are mine?

Comment: The mailman does not deliver the letter your doorstep.  Instead, he opens your mail and shouts out: "this letter is for <name>.  No-one else should listen" and then proceeds to read the letter out loud.

Comment: man, I swear there are a million place on the net you could find an answer for this. This knowledge should only be unknown to you if you've got intermediate to little knowledge about networks, Which; as a developer; you should have more knowledge about how machines work/behave. It annoys me sometimes when developers are unaware of how certain attacks work even when they are in that industry and the type of attack is very widespread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote William Pursell's comment, which he should have made an answer and should have expanded:

> The mailman does not deliver the letter your doorstep. Instead, he opens your mail and shouts out: "this letter is for <name>. No-one else should listen" and then proceeds to read the letter out loud. –

In the original Ethernet network, there was a shared cable to which all hosts were attached; if a host wanted to send a message to another host, it would transmit the packet on the shared cable, with an Ethernet header with the destination Ethernet address of the other host.  *All* hosts on the cable could, in theory, see the packet.  (This was in an era where security was less of a concern; for cases where security was a concern, the packets were encrypted in a fashion that the other host could fairly easily decrypt but that other hosts would have to decrypt in some other more difficult fashion.)

In addition, a packet can be sent to the "broadcast" Ethernet address (all 1's) or a "multicast" Ethernet address (which several hosts are configured to handle); broadcast packets are intended for all hosts on the Ethernet to see, and multicast packets are intended for all hosts in the address's "multicast group" to see.

Normally, an Ethernet adapter would ignore packets that aren't sent to its Ethernet address, to the broadcast Ethernet address, or to a multicast address for which it's configured to receive packets.  Most can, however, be put into "promiscuous" mode, where they pass *all* packets to the host; that mode is used for packet sniffers.

Most current Ethernets are "switched"; instead of a shared cable, there's an Ethernet switch, and hosts plug into the switch with a cable.  Packets sent to a particular host's Ethernet address will only be sent out the switch port for that host (unless somebody's configured the hosts to have a "mirror port" on which all traffic is sent, or unless the switch hasn't yet determined which port is the port for that Ethernet address).  Broadcast packets are sent to all ports, and multicast packets may be sent to all ports or, if the switch can determine that, to those ports that have adapters configured for the multicast address in question.

Wi-Fi networks are similar, but they're usually protected with encryption, as it's easier for somebody to bring in a laptop and put it into "monitor mode" to sniff on a given channel than it is for somebody to bring in a laptop, configure a switch to have a mirror port (or use some other mechanism to get access to the traffic), and plug the laptop into the appropriate port on the switch.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, with switches you are correct. However the person who owns the switch can intercept your traffic at will (in your example that would be the mail service). Also, sometimes the switch can be fooled into rerouting traffic (someone accepts the package on your behalf and then goes through it).

Furthermore, certain kinds of packets need to be broadcast. For instance ARP packets (where one computer is asking for the ethernet address of another computer specified by IP) get broadcast to all ethernet addresses and therefore can get sniffed.

Generally speaking man-in-the-middle requires someone in the connection chain to be compromised. For instance, your ISP or the company they buy transit from could create a man in the middle attack. (This is also why security in countries oppressive regimes is so difficult, they control the internet and therefore can sniff/man-in-the-middle attack whatever they please). This can also be done by compromising the DNS server you use to point you to a different site that can grab your data and forward your data (or a modified version thereof) on to the true site.

In the good 'ol days hubs were quite common (or even older, everyone shared a piece of coax). In this case it's more like the package gets dropped on the first door, the occupant looks to see if it's theirs, if not, passes it on, if so, copies what's inside and passes the package along. In other words, packet sniffing is actually quite easy.

Comment: I would just add a metaphor for the attack on switched environments: When someone (A) want's get packages from someone else (B), he just go to A house and replace his address number, then comes to his house and place A number on it. When mailman comes, deliver the packet to B, B checks it contents and then he run's to A house to leave it there. A never learns this (except he is monitoring his address number plate) and mailman either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes or more simple way packet sniffing not is good, while you login on the web page you normal use a secret password for verify this is you.

But in case we has a packet sniffer she/he can also see and read what you password is.
And laiter login in the web page as you.

Or in she/he can also modify you data on the road to do something other.

[image]
And in the case of internet, the normal way is more the one computer is use to 
send a message from in this case Alice to Alice bank.
And in each of this computer ( right side of image ) is this possible
for the use to edit the message if the use want as in this image.

Eva is use for deliver the message to Alice Bank, but she can 
can read the message/order and in some case edit this to get the bank 
to think Alice want to transfer money to Eva instead of Bob.

In short for protect us against eva to modify the message we can use
hash-algorithm or cryptographer algorithm.